# Get TypeError: Cannot redefine property: useNavigate when using Jest spyOn

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am using Jest + React Testing Library to test my App.

The test file:

```
import { render, screen, waitFor } from "@testing-library/react";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";
import React from "react";
import { MemoryRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import GoBack from "../Goback";

const mockUseNavigate = jest.spyOn(require("react-router-dom"), "useNavigate");
const navigate = mockUseNavigate()

describe("GoBack page", () => {
  const pageInfo =
    "This is error page!";

  it("renders the GoBack page", async () => {
    const { container } = render(
      <MemoryRouter>
        <GoBack />
      </MemoryRouter>
    );

    expect(container).toMatchSnapshot();
    expect(screen.getByText(pageInfo)).toBeInTheDocument();

    const goBackBtn = screen.getByRole("button");
    userEvent.click(goBackBtn);
    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(navigate).toBeCalled();
    });
  });
});
```

I try to `spyOn` the `useNavigate` hook from `react router V6` but when I run the code I got
`TypeError: Cannot redefine property: useNavigate`

Answer (score 3):

Mocking it should work:

```js
jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
  ...(jest.requireActual('react-router-dom')), // since you still want to use the actual MemoryRouter
  useNavigate: () => useNavigateMock,
}))
```